# How to hide or show an input with two select options using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got two select options which I want them to make changes to an input.

This is my js code code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name=Start]').change(function() {
        if (this.value == 'St1') {
            $('#PlPrc').css("display", "");
        }
        else if (this.value == 'St2') {
            if($('select[name=End]').value == 'End1') {
                $('#PlPrc').css("display", "");
            }
            else{
                $('#PlPrc').css("display", "none");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and this is the html code:

```
<select name="Start">
    <option value="St1">End 1</option>
    <option value="St2">End 2</option>
</select>

<select name="End">
    <option value="End1">End 1</option>
    <option value="End2">End 2</option>
</select>

<div id="PlPrc" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="PlPrc" value=""/></div>
```

The problem is that, the javascript code does not process the second if clause where it is:

```
if($('select[name=End]').value == 'End1') {
    $('#PlPrc').css("display", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```
$('select[name=End]').value
```

to

```
$('select[name=End]').val()
```

should do it.

More info on how to get value from a `select` element [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/).